# Insert code right after body tag using theme functions

Tags: drupal, themes, hook, overriding

I am trying to add a piece of code at the begining of *every* page in a Drupal site.
Since I have more than one `page` template, I want to do this programatically... but am not succeeding.

I am still new and, though I get the gist of hooks, theme functions, and the such, I just can't figure the correct way to achieve this.

So far I've overriden the `theme_preprocess_page(&$vars)` to add the necessary css and js:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    if(condition) {
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule').'/js/modal.js');
    }
}
```

How can I now add html code in every drupal page, preferably just after the opening `body`tag or in any other starting section, via a function in the `template.php`file?

Thank you

Comment: There isn't a magic solution. if you want another piece of code after the body (in HTML), u'll have to go through all the page templates you have. You can, however, use JS to create that HTML after page load and prepend it to the body.

Comment: well, I've overriden the breadcrumbs theme function `mytheme_breadcrumb($vars)` to insert the code just above the `$output` and it works, since breadcrumbs are present in every page... but that's a bit ugly, I was hoping some `mytheme_just_after_body`-like function.

Answer (score 3):

In your preprocess function, any variable set, will be available in your page.tpl.php file.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (condition) {
    $vars['foo'] = '<div id="bar">TEST</div>';
  }
}
```

then, in your page templates:

```
<body>
  <?php print !empty($foo) ? $foo : ''; ?>
...
```

Comment: That would make him go over every page template file he has, which he tried to avoid.

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky is exactly right. I already had this option and was trying to avoid touching any *.tpl.php

Answer (score 2):

Had a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/google_tag. This is how they did it:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_alter().
 *
 * Adds a post_render callback
 */
function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  $page['#post_render'][] = 'MYMODULE_CALLBACK';
}

/**
 * Implements callback_post_render().
 *
 * Inserts JavaScript snippet immediately following the opening body tag.
 */
function MYMODULE_CALLBACK(&$children, $elements) {
  $script = '<script type="text/javascript">console.log(\'hello world\');</script>';
  // Insert snippet after the opening body tag.
  $children = preg_replace('@<body[^>]*>@', '$0' . $script, $children, 1);
  return $children;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should keep you from having to modify any code in your templates:

```
function MY_MODULE_page_build(&$page)
{
    $page['page_bottom']['my-markup'] = array('#markup' => '<div>My Markup Here</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach finally was overriding the first rendered block in the page, in my case the Language Switcher.
Since I already was overriding it to customize it, it wasn't too much of a big deal, but it is anyway an ugly way to achieve that.

```
<?php
function mytheme_languageswitcher($links) {
    // inserting this here like a virus in a dna strip
    if(condition) {
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule').'/js/modal.js');
    }
    // the *real* code for the language switcher override
}
?>
```

Since the Language Switcher is rendered in every page, it works. The day the language switcher stops being displayed for whatever reason, this solution will FAIL.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the footer with an option passed into the [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) function.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
   if (condition) {
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEMENAME') . '/PATH/TO/FILE.js', array('scope' => 'footer'));
   }
}
```

This will end up printing just before the closing body tag via the `$page_bottom` variable in the template `html.tpl.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use the native drupal methods `drupal_add_js` and `drupal_get_js`.

// first, add your JS with a custom "scope" (before process phase)

```
<?php
drupal_add_js($tag_js, array(
  'type' => 'inline',
  'group' => JS_GROUP_TAGS,
  'every_page' => TRUE,
  'scope' => 'body_start',
  'weight' => 1,
)); 
?>
```

// ugly way : add the `drupal_get_js` directly into `html.tpl.php` (but for testing, it's useful):

```
<body>
<?php print drupal_get_js('body_start'); ?>
...
</body>
```

// A cleaner way : use an intermediate variable, in a process method
// Exactly like `template_process_html`, in `theme.inc`

```
<?php
function MYMODULEORTHEME_process_html(&$variables){
  $variables['js_body_start'] .= drupal_get_js('body_start');
}
?>
```

Enjoy :)